# Webclient onStatus does not work in case of 406 returned from downstream API

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflux

I'm doing a `onStatus` implementation in my API when I use a webclient (Webflux) to call external API:

```
//Webclient Call

    Flux<Movie> movies = webclient.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(api_url)
                    .build(author))
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        response -> Mono.error(new AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException(response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase())))
                    .bodyToFlux(Movie.class)


//Global Handler Exception Class


    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
        @ExceptionHandler(AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<?> AcceptHeaderHandling(AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException exception){
    
            ApiException apiException = new ApiException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), exception.getMessage());
    
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiException, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    
    }

//AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException Class

    public class AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException extends RuntimeException{

       public AcceptHeaderNotsupportedException(String message){
          super(message);
}

    }


//Api custom Exception

       public class ApiCustomException{
        
            private int code;
        
            private String message;
        
        }
```

I am testing a scenario webclient call that return a 406 error from downstream api. So i want to map the response to my object representation and give to my client (postman in this case).

```
{
  code: 406,
  "message": error from downstream api
}
```

but i am getting to client

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-08-29T14:31:00.944+00:00",
  "path": "path",
  "status": 406,
  "error": "Not Acceptable",
  "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
  "requestId": "ba66698f-1",
  "trace": "org.springframework.web.server.NotAcceptableStatusException: 406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE \"Could not find acceptable representation\"\n\tat ....}
```

In case of a 404 error from downstream API the mapping response works fine.

```
{
  code: 404,
  "message": not found 
}
```

My question is if i am doing **.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError** should not work for both (404, 406 or other responde code with 4xx ?

Comment: Please elaborate more `when it is 406 (when i send a accept: application/xml and external api not allow) does not work and give me a default error spring structure` almost says nothing about the current behaviour. Also no logs, are supplied so its very hard, bordering impossible to know what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Toerktumlare like i said i am using a webclient to call external api. In case of that api return a 404 error, my webclient handle the response through onStatus code above (.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError). But with a scenario that API give me a 406, the webclient not handle and 406 is the same group than 404 (HttpStatus::is4xxClientError).
Shouldn't have the same effect (404 or 406 or 4xx) ?

Comment: You just repeated what you wrote, what do you men `not handle` where are the logs, you need to show us the behaviour, not just write ”its not handled” how is it handled?

Comment: @Toerktumlare the main topic is updated. It's better ? thanks

Comment: and when you are debugging is the onStatus even called?

Comment: this is my problem, 404 is caught by OnStatus but the 406 not. I am not understand why or the difference because both are 4xx erros but i think the 406 is never caught because i force a true predicate with print to console and it's still not on OnStatus.

Comment: I stumbled across the same issue now. 
Expecting: 
{
error: "Not Found",
message: "Entity by <ID> not found"
}

I can see the exception reaching my GlobalExceptionHandler. But somehow, what I am getting in console is different:

{
 "timestamp": "2023-02-23T07:40:48.057+00:00",
 "status": 404,
 "error": "Not Found",
 "path": "/v1/entities/{id}"
}